# And statements using Handlebar

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am wondering if is possible to make something like that using a possible AND statement in handlebar:
If not what is the best way to make have the same result.

---

This is the javascript context:

```
{
  title: "My first post!",
  author: {
    firstName: "Charles",
    lastName: "Jolley"
  }
}
```

---

This is the HTML context:

```
<div class="entry">
  {{#if firstName && lastName}}
  <h1>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</h1>
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the native `{{#if}}` doesn't understand that syntax. However, you can easily [add your own helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#conditionals) for something like that and you can even work with an unknown number of arguments to your helper if you don't mind messing around with [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments).

The only tricky part is noting that the block argument to a helper always comes last.

Something simple like this will do the trick:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('if_all_true', function() {
    var args  = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var block = args.pop();
    for(var i = 0; i < args.length; ++i)
        if(!args[i])
            return block.inverse(this);
    return block(this);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/jMLcZ/